# How can I implement drag-and-drop to allow rearranging items in a ListView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, drag-and-drop

I would like to enable support for drag-and-drop in a ListView so that the user can rearrange the items, similar to what they can do in Windows Explorer.

Specifically, how do I enable the Drag event handler when I double-click on the ListView ?

This is what I get after double-clicking on the ListView :

```
private void listView1(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

However, I want it to be:

```
private void listView(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
```

How can I do this?

I have tried many ways, such as:

```
  private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      // Enable drag and drop for this form
      // (this can also be applied to any controls)
      this.AllowDrop = true;

      // Add event handlers for the drag & drop functionality
      this.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(Form_DragEnter);
      this.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(Form_DragDrop);
 }
```

But none of these seem to work.

Comment: See these existing implementations: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/dragdroplistviewreorder1.aspx and http://www.csharphelp.com/archives/archive263.html

Comment: Please explain exactly where you want to drag **from** and where you want to drag **to**.  Each drag operation has a start and an end point, and implementation depends on that.  The start point might even be Windows, so we need more information.

Answer (score 7):

You need to implement the **DragEnter** event and set the Effect property of the DragEventArgs. The **DragEnter** event is what allows things to be dropped into a control. After that the **DragDrop** event will fire when the mouse button is released.

Here is a version that will allow objects to be dropped into the a ListView:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.AllowDrop = true;
        listView1.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(listView1_DragDrop);
        listView1.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(listView1_DragEnter);
    }

    void listView1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }

    void listView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add(e.Data.ToString());
    }
```

No doubt your sample code was taken from : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.allowdrop(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question: There is no built in functionality for dragging and dropping items within a ListView control. Even the MSDN documentation instructs you to implement your own code-behind for the various events in order to achieve this functionality (see the [ListViewInsertionMark Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewinsertionmark.aspx))

Answer (score -1):

[ObjectListView](https://web.archive.org/web/20161121000010/http://www.codeproject.com:80/KB/list/objectlistview.aspx) (an open source wrapper around .NET WinForms ListView) provides this ability without further work (plus lots of other [nice features](https://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/features.html)). Have a look at the "Drag and Drop" tab of the demo.

[image: Screenshot of ObjectListView in use, showing drag-and-drop insertion caret.]

<sub>(source: [codeproject.com](https://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView/dragdrop-dropbetween.png))</sub>